# NSUserDefaults vs CFPreferences, what to consider

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsuserdefaults, cfpreferences

Apple provides documentation for managing user preferences through both [Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001450) and [Foundation Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It also doesn't offer any help with choosing one or another, except for stating that they're indeed different (*"not toll-free bridged"*).

So, I'm interested, is there anything I should consider selecting configuration mechanism for the application? Or should I just toss a coin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are supposed to use `NSUserDefaults`, which is absolutely the default choice. I suppose you could use `CFPreferences`, but unless you had a good reason to make that choice, I'd steer clear of `CF`-APIs.

Comment: I didn't stumble on `CFPreferences` accidentally, those functions are used in several apple tutorials, e.g. [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Tasks/Sample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000710-BABFCABJ). But thanks for the input, I was looking to hear from somebody with experience.

Comment: Also, is there any particular reason to *steer clear of CF-APIs* ?

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: They're typically harder to use (at the least because there's no built-in easy way to autorelease CF objects). CFPreferences specifically is designed to enable you to work with any application's preferences, not just your own, and for that, it's actually easier. For working with your own prefs, NSUserDefaults is easier, so you should use that for that reason.

Comment: No problem! You want to steer clear of `CF`-APIs because they're procedural, complicated, and low-level. Use Objective-C. In 99.99% of situations, there's no reason to do anything different. Never ask the question, “Why shouldn’t I do this complicated and terrible thing?”. Ask the question, “The canonical, simple solution isn’t working; will this other complicated solution help solve my problem?”. Since you presumably aren’t doing anything out of the ordinary, there is no reason not to use the ordinary, canonical solution.

Comment: @Peter Thanks to both of you. I indeed didn't know that CF was an outcast in apple world :)

Comment: CF == CoreFoundation. It's lower level API than AppKit, it's a straight (non Objective-) C API, and yes, unless you have a specific reason to use it, you should generally prefer the higher-level API.  Typical reasons you might use CF would be if you were writing something with no ObjC in it (say porting some C open source prog), if the exposed Objective-C API imposed limitations that you needed to get around, or if the performance overhead of the Objective-C wrappers was somehow significant for your particular use case.

Comment: for those who don't know: to autorelease toll free bridged (=several) CFNSTypes you can just use the default autorelease mechanism once appropriately typecasted: `[(NSString*)myCFString autorelease]`. of course, you may prefer something more specialized. more importantly: i wouldn't dissuade somebody from using CoreFoundation. it's an excellent library; a good portion of Foundation acts as an objc wrapper for its interfaces. i don't find it complicated, terrible, or an outcast. lastly, many people use and/or prefer CoreFoundation APIs directly.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: It's not an outcast, it's just usually harder to use. Not always, just usually. When a CF solution is the best solution, there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: @ipmcc: Core Foundation and AppKit aren't comparable. It used to be true that *Foundation* was based on Core Foundation, but they're increasingly intermingled, to the point where, for some things, there's no difference but syntax.

Comment: @Justin: Better to go through `NSMakeCollectable`: `[NSMakeCollectable(myCFString) autorelease]`. Then your code works in GC projects as well. But either way is a pain to type repeatedly (so, not easy); the only solution to that is to wrap it in a function (not built-in). Using Cocoa APIs, where available, solves that because you can autorelease with less work and often with none.

Comment: @Peter Hosey good addition. since CF/NS-MakeCollectable is only required once per object and my example contained no creation call or exit, i omitted it for clarity. personally, i've wrapped it, which is also useful in order to compile c and c++ translations. a function which wraps the functionality required is comparably monotonous to type as `[*arg* autorelease]` is -- there's no more to type in many cases.

Comment: @Justin: True; it's the cases where you don't need to say `autorelease` at all that the savings come in.

Comment: @PeterHosey: Yeah, NSUserDefaults is in Foundation.framework, not AppKit.framework. My bad. s/AppKit/Foundation/

Comment: @Peter Hosey yup - i've opted to avoid much of that noise for years (although not in every project i've been involved in during that time), favoring SBRM.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults reads and writes to the user scope, while CFPreferences supports writing to both user scope and machine scope. You can use CFPreferences for a machine-wise setting which can be applied to all users using the application on the same machine.